# Hashing with two functions vs one

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, hash

Which is better having two hash functions with each result being n/2 bits or having one hash function with the end result being n bits. Can we even make either of the statements in general, or the performance depends totally on the use case : what types of string I am trying to hash.

Example: Lets say I am hashing normal strings which can be long (10^5),
Checking collisions using two approach:

1. Using two hash functions h1(x) and h2(x) with the result being two *int* types, and comparing them individually to guess equality.
2. Using a single hash function with the result being *long int*.

Is either approach better(low probability of collisions) then the other?

Comment: How do you define "better"? Low probability of collisions? Computation speed? Or what are the important properties for you? What do use the hash function for? Creating a hash table? Checking for document equality?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'better'

What is important that you have as little collisions as possible. If you can achieve this using one hash-function that is as good as if you get a similar low number of collisions while using multible hash functions.

By the way combining multible hash functions is again one slightly complex hash function.

So if you need a hash function you might consider:

- what data do I have to perform the hash function on? Can I use any of this knowledge to create a hash function that will most likely lead to view collisions?
- how expensive (memory, computing-time) is my hash function. Maybe a faster one is more appropriate even if there are a little more collisions.

I recommend to always profile the performance of different approaches with   real life data to decide which is the best for the job.